# unable to print string while concatenation using toupper() function

Tags: c++, c++14

I am facing issues while using toupper() function : 
**Code** :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main (){
    string input {"ab"};
    string output {""};
    cout << output + toupper(input[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

the **error** is : 
no operator "+" matches these operands -- operand types are: std::_cx11::string + int .
but if i write :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main (){
    string input {"ab"};
    string output {""};
    char temp = toupper(input[0]);
    cout << output + temp;
    return 0;
}
```

it works fine. can anyone tell why ?

Comment: toupper returns int, not char (`int toupper( int ch );
`), string + int is impossible.

Comment: `toupper` returns `int`, not `char`. There is no overload for `operator +` against `std::string` and `int`, but there is one for `std::string` and `char`. See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`toupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper)'s return value is an `int`, and you can't add an `std::string` and an `int` due to no existing `operator+(int)`. Your `char temp` implicitly converts the `int` return value to `char` during its initialization, and since `std::string` has an `operator+(char)` overload, this works. Though you can replicate the same behavior with a `static_cast` instead:

```
cout << output + static_cast<char>(toupper(input[0]));
```

As a side note, `ctype` functions generally a expect value that is representable as `unsigned char`, or `EOF`, to be passed, so you should convert `char` arguments to `unsigned char` before passing them.